# Why TypeError after adding properties to an observable object in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typeerror, observable, ko.observablearray

I was playing around with building a custom handler which adds new observableArray-properties to parts of MyViewModel to make sure the nested templates within elements bound by my handlers would always have the right arrays - [**see jsfiddle for full example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/DmTX3/).

```
<div data-bind="contentAvailable: ['children','pos1']">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'default', foreach: children().pos1 }">
</div>
```

Within the handler I checked if the current object `bindingContext.$data` had an observable object as a property with the name as `valueAccessor()[0]` (in my example 'children') and if that observable object in turn had an observable array of it's own with the name `valueAccessor()[1]` ('pos1') - and in case of absence I would assing them.

At first I tried [valueHasMutated() and reseting the observable as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010058/dynamically-adding-properties-to-observable-object)

```
//within the handler
bindingContext.$data[valueAccessor()[0]]()[valueAccessor()[1]]=ko.observableArray([]);
//and after ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel) 
child1.children().pos1().push(new ViewChild(2));
child1.children().pos1.valueHasMutated();
```

This almost-worked - since I didn't want to notify about mutation every time I push a value I tried to place the `valueHasMutated()` within the handler - after adding the `observableArray()` but that would result in `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` (tho `typeof` 1 line above says otherwise XD ).

Am I using those object refrences in a fundamentally wrong way or just lacking some understanding in how knockout does it's magic? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still kind of digesting what you are trying to do, but noticed that you do have a typo where you have `i(1)` instead of `i[1]` in the `typeof` check in your binding handler:

```
if(!bC.$data[i[0]]().hasOwnProperty(i[1]) || typeof bC.$data[i[0]]()[i(1)] !== 'function'){           
        var existing = bC.$data[i[0]]();
```

Comment: well yes that's embarrassing :) tho removing the typo didn't get me closer to what I wanted. My initial problem was that when I wanted to use a template on an object which didn't have some of the properties to witch parts of the template were bound to, I would get an error. At first I tried using a simple 'if' binding to avioid errors and later add the properties, but that also failed to update the dom..

Comment: I think that it could work to create your observables/observableArrays on-the-fly like you are doing.  Another approach would be using an observable to hold the entire object that is populated later. Then, the `if` binding would kick in whenever the observable was populated with your object.